# Find the derivative of $\exp(x^x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $\exp (x^x)$

My Attempt:

Let 
$$y=\exp (x^x)$$
Taking $\textrm {ln}$ on both sides,.
$$\ln (y)=\ln \exp (x^x)$$
$$\ln (y)=x\ln (e^x)$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t  $x$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}=x.\dfrac {1}{e^x} .e^x+ \ln (e^x)$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}=x+\ln (e^x)$$
$$y'=\exp (x^x) (x+\ln (e^x))$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you mean $e^\left(x^x\right)$ or $\left(e^x\right)^x$?

Comment: @mathestar, I meant the first one.

Comment: In that case, you cannot pull x out of the logarithm, you would need to pull out $x^x$

Comment: Your notation is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I've fixed your notation to (hopefully) clarify the ambiguity. I hope I haven't change the substance of what you meant in the process. Please alert me if I have.

Comment: See related question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/992501/19266

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the way I imagine you were taught, you would need to take a logarithm twice:

$$ 
y = e^{x^x} \\
\ln(y) = \ln(e^{x^x}) \\
\ln(y) = x^x \\
\ln(\ln(y)) = \ln(x^x) \\
\ln(\ln(y)) = x\,\ln(x) \\
$$

Now you can take the derivative:

$$
\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{1}{x} + \ln(x) \\
\frac{1}{\ln(y)}\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + \ln(x) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = y\,\ln(y)\,(1 + \ln(x))
$$

Substituting in $y = e^{x^x}$ yields
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x^x}\,\ln(e^{x^x})\,(1 + \ln(x)) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x^x}\,x^x\,(1 + \ln(x))
$$

However, there is actually a rule that they NEVER tell you that you can also use:

$$ d(u^v) = vu^{v - 1}\,du + \ln(u)\,u^v\,dv $$

This rule eliminates the whole process of taking logarithms.
Let's see it applied:

$$ 
y = e^{x^x} \\
d(y) = d(e^{x^x}) \\
dy = e^{x^x} d(x^x) \\
dy = e^{x^x} (x\cdot x^{x - 1}\,dx + \ln(x)x^x\,dx) \\
dy = e^{x^x} (x\cdot x^{x - 1} + \ln(x)x^x)\,dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x^x} (x\cdot x^{x - 1} + \ln(x)x^x)
$$
This is the same result as before, just factored differently.  As you can see $x\cdot x^{x - 1}$ is the same as $x^x$.  That gives
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x^x} (x^x + \ln(x)x^x) $$
Then you can factor out x^x from the parenthesis and get the original result:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x^x} x^x\,(1 + \ln(x)) $$
I just wanted to point this out to you because SO many Calculus courses leave out this really great rule!

Additionally, even though it looks ugly, it is really just a combination of the power rule and the exponentiation rule.

Answer (score 1):

Due to ambiguity, it's better to separate in the two cases.

**Case 1**

$$f(x) = (e^x)^x$$

In this case the function is also equal to $f(x) = e^{x^2}$ whence it's derivative follows the exponential of a function rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{f(x)} = e^{f(x)}f'(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{x^2} = 2x e^{x^2}$$

**Case 2**

Your function is

$$g(x) = e^{x^x}$$

The same rule as before holds, and you get

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{x^x} = e^{x^x} x^x (\ln (x)+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

No: $\;\ln y=x^x=\mathrm e^{x\ln x}$, so 
\begin{align}\frac{y'}y&=\mathrm e^{x\ln x}\Bigl(\ln x+x\cdot\frac1x\Bigr)=x^x(\ln x+1)\\\text{whence }\qquad y'&=y\,x^x(\ln x+1). \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$y = \exp z(x)$, where $z(x)=x^x$.

$y' = z'(x)\exp z(x).$

$z(x)= \exp (x (\ln x))$.

$z'(x) = (x \ln x)' z(x) = (\ln x +1)x^x$.

Altogether:

$y'= (\ln x+1)x^x\exp (x^x)$.