# How can I prove $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}...}}}}=2$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation, tetration

How can I prove

> $$\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}...}}}}=2$$

I don't know which method can be used for this?

Comment: You can start by defining what $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^\ldots}$ is.

Comment: There are several things related to convergence of $x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}$ i.e., an infinite exponentiation that you might want to check first. Firstly it only makes sense when $x \in [e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$, then you use monotone convergence to finish the task ! :)

Comment: [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/984594/81360)

Comment: Wouldn't it also fast, if you just look at $ | 2 - a_n| < \epsilon $ and then show there is always an $ a_n $ in $ (a_n)_n $, so that this inequation is true $\forall \epsilon > 0$ ? 

Well, someone had still to show that this series is strictly monotone rising. 
Personally I find this approach more intuitive, though most proofs for this work in a very similar fashion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can define $x=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}...}}}}$ as follows:

Let $x_1 = \sqrt 2$ and $x_{n+1} = (\sqrt 2)^{x_{n}}$

We can show $x_n \lt 2\ \forall n$ by induction, since if $y \lt 2$, then $(\sqrt 2)^y \lt 2$. And $x_n$ is clearly monotonically increasing, so $x_n \to x$.

But $$x_{n+1} = (\sqrt 2)^{x_{n}}$$
so taking limits, we get that $$x = (\sqrt 2)^{x}$$

Solving this, and using the fact that $x \le 2$ gives $x =2$.

Comment: I probably miss something, but if the sequence $x_n$ is bounded above bu $x$ and monotone, it converges, but it doesn't necessarily converge to $x$

Comment: @Alex $x$ is *defined* as the limit of the $x_n$. This is the most natural way to make sense of the infinite series of powers.

Answer (score 7):

**Step One.** Define the recursive sequence
$$
a_0=\sqrt{2}, \quad a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}^{a_n},\,\,n\in\mathbb N.
$$

**Step Two.** Show that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing (inductively), and upper bounded by $2$ (also inductively).

**Step Three.** Due to *Step Two* the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent. Let $a_n\to x$. Clearly, $\sqrt{2}<x\le 2$.
But $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}^{a_n}\to x$, as well. Hence 
$$
x=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2}^{a_n}=\sqrt{2}^x.
$$
Thus $x$ satisfies $\sqrt{2}^x=x$.

**Step Four.** Show that $x<\sqrt{2}^x$, for all $x\in (\sqrt{2},2)$, and thus $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $x_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}^{x_n}$.

Prove by induction that $x_n \leq x_{n+1} \leq 2$. As the sequence is bounded and increasing, it is convergent, and the limit is between $x_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $2$.

Finish the proof by observing that 
$$\sqrt{2}^x=x$$
has an unique solution on the interval $[\sqrt{2}, 2]$.

For the last part, as well as for the monotony, you should study first the monotony/sign of $x-\sqrt{2}^x$ on $  [\sqrt{2}, 2]$

Comment: Is there a way to solve $\sqrt{2}^x=x$ without making a function: $f(x)=x-\sqrt{2}^x$?