# A peculiar observation about infinity.

Tags: infinity, tetration

Let ${\sqrt2^\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2^...}=y$.

Then $\sqrt 2^y=y$

$\implies \sqrt 2=y^{1/y}$
$\implies \sqrt 2 =1$
$\implies  2 =1$ !! but how come that be. Can anyone explain this and point out what is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: How is $y^{\frac 1 y} = 1$? In fact, I'm almost certain that it's not.

Comment: @MatthewLevy Probably $y^{1/y}=y^{1}/y=1$. :-D

Comment: lol, okay must be a first year calculus student or something. I see that error all the time

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077576/how-can-i-prove-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-2) similar question !

Answer (score 3):

First, the value of that power tower is 2. (Which converges for $e^{-e}\le x\le e^{1/e}$)
Then we can see that $$\sqrt{2}=2^{1/2}=\sqrt2.$$
You are assuming $y=1$ and therefore simplifying $y^{1/y}$ to 1.

Comment: What is $x$? What notion of convergence is being used?

Comment: Sequence of finite towers.. obviously

Comment: x is the value that is being tetrated, in this case, $\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt 2=y^{1/y}$ has solutions $y=2$ or $y=4$, though one of these is implausible for the power tower